# Ansible breaks the loop when using include

Tags: json, loops, ansible

I am trying to run multiple tasks in a loop, but whenever I get an error inside the loop, ansible exits out of it.
I want to be able to run the loop until the end of the list for each item. If something breaks for an item, the loop stops only for this item, not for the rest.

My inventory structure is json, but looks something like this:

```
webhost1:
  items: 
      [item1, item2]
```

My ansible playbook does this:

```
  - include: multiple_tasks_to_be_run_for_each_item.yml
    with_items: items
```

The expected result is similar to running:

```
  - shell: /bin/false
    with_items:
       - "1"
       - "2"
       - "3"
```

Even if it fails on the first item, it continues to run.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands

Comment: I don't want to just skip the failed tasks, just skip that item. Afterwards ansible reports host as failed, so I know something happened there.

Comment: Hello, in accordance with the site, you should show that you tried different solution, and not just asking for an help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is the expected behaviour. Answer from [github issue here.](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/70311)

> This is working as intended. Use `block` and `rescue` to control failure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with loop, loop_control and loop_var within Ansible Role, and let me know if it helps.

```
sample.yml
-----------
    - include_tasks: "repeat.yml"
      loop: "{{ list_of_values }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: var1


repeat.yml ( You can use the var1 inside the repeat.yml)
-----------

---
- name: Repeat Tasks
  block:
    - name : task 1
      .........

    - name : task 2
      .........
```

Comment: I think there is bug in ansible itself.
"The primary advantage of using include* statements is looping. When a loop is used with an include, the included tasks or role will be executed once for each item in the loop."
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#differences-between-dynamic-and-static

I tried it with roles, but it still doesn't work like a simple task loop.

I will raise a bug in ansible git to see what the team will answer.